# Transposed Direct Form II

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-filters

In the book digital Signal Processing by Proakis 4th Edition, at page 593 a table is drawn about some second order modules for discrete time systems. In that table there Transposed Form II drawn But when I searched the net, it was drawn completely opposite to that drawn in the book. On the internet, the input and output were placed on right and left respectively. I want to ask that which form is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct-Form II is the canonical structure to implement a given LCCDE, using minimum number of delay elements and multiplications. Conventionally, its input, $x[n]$, is placed on the left, and the output, $y[n]$, on the right.

DF-II structure implements the poles of LCCDE (its IIR part) before its zeros (FIR part). This may be undesirable for high gain poles, causing potential numerical instability.

The **transposed** DF-II structure implements zeros first, and poles later, therefore, avoids the (potential) numerical instability of DF-II structure while retaining its canonical advantage. It's obtained by reversing all branch directions, and replacing sum nodes with signal nodes, and also replacing (and renaming) input/output output nodes so that input applied at the right, and output emerges at the left.

To comply with the convention that the input is applied at the left node, the transposed DF-II structure is horizontally **flipped**. This way, input $x[n]$ appears at the left again.

Both forms of transposed DF-II are equivalent.

[image]

Comment: I hope it's okay I added that image, Fat.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson well thanks! I should have added that already...